# PERMITIR EL USO DE LA CAMARA Y EL MICROFONO EN FIREFOX CON SELENIUM Y PYTHON 3.7

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, popup, notificaciones

Deseo saber como puedo permitir el uso de la camara y el microfono usando firefox con selenium y python.
Es decir escoger la opcion permitir.
[image: Ayuda!!!]

Answer (score 0):

Con la siguiente sentencia:

```
options.set_preference(...)
```

"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,

Puedes encontrarla aquí

> https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.options.Options.set_preference

set_preference(self, name, value)

Comment: GRACIAS... ME FUNCIONO CON ESTO:                                                
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("permissions.default.microphone", 1)
profile.set_preference("permissions.default.camera", 1)                            
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido. Saludos!